# Extracting InDesign CS4 Graphics using C# and COM

Tags: c#, com, graphics, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to get details of the graphics in an InDesign file.  For technical reasons I'm using COM.  Not my favourite, as (discussed elsewhere in StackOverflow) you have to spend half your life casting.  In Theory (!), the code snippet belwo should work.  Intellisense shows ***doc.AllGraphics***  as returning ***objects***.

The CS3 scripting reference at http://www.indesignscriptingreference.com/CS3/JavaScript/Document.htm shows it as ***Array of Graphic***

```
for (int g = 1; g <= doc.AllGraphics.Count; g++) {
  InDesign.Graphic graphic = (InDesign.Graphic) doc.AllGraphics[ g ];
  ....
}
```

However, I get this error message:

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'InDesign.Graphic'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call
>   on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID
>   '{6AE52037-9E4E-442D-ADFC-2D492B4BCBEF}'
>   failed due to the following error: No
>   such interface supported (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I've tried using alternative constructs to return an object and then cast this to an ***Indesign.Graphic***.  All fail with the same error.  I can't believe that Adobe missed including this interface.

Any suggestions as to a solution so I can get the graphic content?

Answer (score 1):

I am running Win7 64 and CS4 here and had the E_NOInterface message too. 
It took me 6 hours to solve it via google, try and error. On my way thru the internet I saw your posting here and came back to write you what helped me.

During install the Com-Objects are not registered correctly. To solve this

- go to the folder

  - for cs3: `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Adobe\InDesign\Version 5.0\Scripting Support\5.0`
    in my case: `C:\ProgramData\Adobe\InDesignVersion 5.0\Scripting Support\5.0`
  - for cs4: `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Adobe\InDesign\Version 5.0\Scripting Support\6.0`
- rename the file "Resources for Visual Basic.tlb" to "Resources for Visual Basic.tlb.old"
- open up a command window as administrator
- go to the indesign-Folder, in my case `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CS4`
- and launch indesign in the command window by typing:

  ```
  indesign.exe -type
  ```

wait for the launch and then you  are good to go. with this parameter it registeres the components.

I found that solution [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1105924#1105924)

Comment: Unfortunately in XP although it recreates the TLB nd adding this as a COM reference to VS2005 turns it into an InterOp DLL it still doesn't work.  But thanks for the try.

Comment: Worked for me.  After re-naming the file I just re-launched InDesign CS4 using "Run As Administrator" and that worked.  I didn't need to do the indesign.exe -type piece.

Comment: because of this solution it only took me 1.5 hours to fix for me :) thanks for coming back around.

Answer (score 1):

This has just happened to me, and I landed here from Google! I managed to solve it so will add the solution here for the next time I run into it!

Simply, delete the `Resources for Visual Basic.tlb` file that may be at the path of `C:\ProgramData\Adobe\InDesign\Version 8.0\en_GB\Scripting Support\8.0` and open InDesign as Administrator and wait for it to run.

I found the C# application to hang when I ran it next, so had to close InDesign down, and let C# open it up by itself! Example:

```
        Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application");
        Application app = (Application)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        var doc = app.Documents.Add();

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            doc.Pages.Add(idLocationOptions.idAtBeginning);
```