# COM returns type that does not implement any interface

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, adobe-indesign

I need to automate some tasks in Adobe InDesign CS3 from a .NET 4.0 application. I've added a reference to the InDesign Type Library using the Add Reference dialog in Visual Studio. It genereates an interop assembly, which correctly includes all of the interfaces and types declared in the type library. I haven't installed any Adobe SDK, as the type library was available in Visual Studio without installing anything but Adobe InDesign CS3.

The interesting types in the interop assembly for me right now is the interfaces `_Application` and `Application`, and the class `ApplicationClass`. Here is the definition of them, so you can see the relationship between them:

```
public interface _Application
{
    // Lots of properties and methods
}

public interface Application : _Application
{
    // Empty
}

public class ApplicationClass : _Application, Application
{
    // The same properties and methods as declared in _Application
}
```

I try to instantiate the COM object like this:

```
Type oType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application.CS3");
if (oType != null)
{
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(oType);
}
```

This code succeeds. I get an instance, but of a type called `__ComObject`. From what I know, this is completely normal.

Now, here's where the fun begins. For this instance to be usable to me, I should cast it to the correct interface. From other examples on the net, and from the [documentation available here](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/app_notes/id_obj_model.htm), I can see I should cast it to the `Application` interface. But if I do that, I get a nasty `InvalidCastException` saying that the type `System.__ComObject` doesn't support this interface. I get the same exception if I try to cast it to `ApplicationClass` or the `_Application` interface.

I thought I was perhaps using an incorrect interface, so I tried implementing the utility function [listed here](http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-com-object-system__comobject-with-visual-c-net/). This function loops through all the interfaces declared in the interop assembly and queries the IUnknown interface if it implements the interface.

When I use that function, it returns null, meaning that the instance I get back from `CreateInstance` supports *none* of the interfaces in the interop assembly. Surely, that can't be right!?

However, if I inspect the `instance` variable with the Visual Studio Debugger, there's something called "Dynamic View". If I expand that, it lists all the properties for the object and all the properties match the properties from the `ApplicationClass` class and the `_Application` interface. So I tried using `Type.InvokeMember` and that works:

```
oType.InvokeMember("DoScript", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, oArguments, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This actually works, but it would be extremely cumbersome to interact with the COM object like this, and I need to do alot of interaction with the COM object, so this is not really usable. I guess I could make a wrapper for the COM objects, but that kind of defeats the purpose of the interop assembly, and I don't want to create 700+ wrapper classes.

I've searched alot, and I've found tutorials and examples of using the InDesign COM object, but they all just cast the instance returned to the Application interface, but as explained, this doesn't work in my case.

I've also tried the following code instead of the code above:

```
InDesign.Application app = new InDesign.Application();
app.Activate();
```

The first line succeeds and I get an instance of `ApplicationClass`, but when it tries to execute the second line I get a InvalidCastException stating that `ApplicationClass` cannot be converted to the interface `_Application`.

I'm really cornered up here, and not sure what to try next. I really hope someone more experienced with COM and .NET has an idea of what I could be doing wrong.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for such a long post.

Comment: The C# 4.0 *dynamic* keyword was made to make the first code easier to write.  Or use VB.NET.  Try using _Application instead of Application in the second snippet.

Comment: I will try to install Adobe SDK, in case Visual stuido CS3 Api's are mucked up.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried your suggestion to create an instance of the `_Application` interface, but it fails at compile time, saying **Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'InDesign._Application'**. I think the reason that I can create an  instance of `Application` (Which is also an interface), is that the compiler makes some tricks and actually instantiates `ApplicationClass` instead. I read something about that on a blog, but unfortunately I can't find it right now.

Comment: When you say that you are casting it to the (Application) interface, you actually mean that you are casting it to the (InDesign.Application) interface... right?

Comment: @MatsT Yes, that's right. :-) I'm explicitly casting it to `InDesign.Application`.

Comment: @SSamra I tried installing the Adobe InDesign SDK, but it has made no difference. The SDK doesn't even contain the type library needed by Visual Studio to create the interop assembly. The SDK contains tools to create plugins to InDesign, but not anything to help using the COM component of InDesign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a [Runtime Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx)

The method you need is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.createwrapperoftype.aspx)

Try this :

```
    Type oType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application.CS3");
    if (oType != null)
    {
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(oType);// or any other way you can get it
        Application app = 
            (Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(instance, typeof(ApplicationClass));
    }
```

Comment: Wow! You're absolutely right! That works! Thank you so much! :-D
I thought that the interop assembly _was_ the Runtime Callable Wrapper. I'll definitely read the link you gave. Thanks again!

Comment: But what about the properties and methods on the RCW, that returns `__ComObject`. Are they wrapped automatically, or do I need to do some special tricks when receiving them from method calls for example?

Comment: I'm not sure but as far as I can remember, the `Application` methods and properties should return the interfaces defined in the interop. If not, you'll have to wrap everything. Please let me know :-)

Comment: Just a quick followup. All the returned objects are correctly wrapped, so I only had to wrap the `Application` instance. But some of the methods returns `object` types which I have to cast myself to the correct type. But this also works without any problems. So all is good. Thanks again for your help, it's much appreciated! :-)

Comment: I had to set property "Embed Interop Types" of the reference to the InDesign Type Library to false.

Comment: If I set property to "Embed Interop Types" I yet get anther error: "Source object cannot be converted to the destination type since it does not support all the required interfaces."

Answer (score 1):

@Seb solution is the correct one, but while working on it, I came across error "Source object cannot be converted to the destination type since it does not support all the required interfaces." (as @MikeKeskinov wrote it in comments).

To get rid of that error, you need to register COM objects by doing these steps (already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233749/10235741)) - this is for InDesign CC2021 v16.0 (it's similar for other versions)

- Close all instances of InDesign using Task Manager
- Go to `C:\ProgramData\Adobe\InDesign\Version 16.0\en_US\Scripting Support\16.0` and rename tlb file to tlb.bak (or something similar, it doesn't matter)
- Open command window (CMD) as administrator
- Go to InDesign EXE folder `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign 2021`
- Start command `indesign.exe -type`
- Reference newly created tlb file to project

And after that it should work. Hope I helped to someone!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with COM recently but as far I remember (and understood your problem) you can not cast ComObject like this:

```
   Application app = (Application)comObject;
```

but you should use *as* operator:

```
    Application = comObject as Application;
```

Comment: the result of the dynamic cast is `null` as __ComObject isn't related to Application in the .net model.