# Can comObject be cast to Excel.ApplicationClass?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

I'm using

```
(Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
```

It returns me a `_ComObject` type but I was wondering how I'd be able to cast that to `Excel.ApplicationClass`, and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Is the following any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757255/com-returns-type-that-does-not-implement-any-interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The KB article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126) defines that the following will work.

```
//Excel Application Object
Excel.Application oExcelApp;

this.Activate();

//Get reference to Excel.Application from the ROT.
oExcelApp =  (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

//Display the name of the object.
MessageBox.Show(oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name);

//Release the reference.
oExcelApp = null;
```