# How to solve 0x80004002 error on InDesign 2020 COM with C#?

Tags: c#, com, interop, adobe-indesign

Does anybody knows how to solve the same problem in InDesign 2020 and VS 2019?
[Extracting InDesign CS4 Graphics using C# and COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134119/extracting-indesign-cs4-graphics-using-c-sharp-and-com)

I don't have any file tlb or the Scripting Support folder...

There is my code:

```html
public void IndesignFile(){
    try {
          Type inDesignAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application.2020");
          InDesign.Application myInDesign (InDesign.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(inDesignAppType);
         var myString = myInDesign.DoScript("return \"My String\"", InDesign.idScriptLanguage.idJavascript, new object[] { "" });
            }catch(Exception e)
            {}
        }
```

And I am getting this error:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'InDesign.Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{ABD4CBB2-0CFE-11D1-801D-0060B03C02E4}' failed due to the following error: Não há suporte para esta interface (0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Could anybody help me, please?

Comment: Where do you get the tlb/com reference that contains Indesign.Application from? Otherwise you can try the dynamic way: `dynamic app = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application.2020"));` etc...

Comment: Typical mishap for a C# console project.  Put the `[STAThread]` attribute on the Main() method.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Using dynamic works! Thank you!
Now the problem is with DoScript... "'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'DoScript'"

Comment: Like I say, where do you get your tlb or .net import library?

Comment: I was able to get it to work using dynamic and it did not complain (surprisingly) that there was no "DoScript" method.